# disable WP_error: authentication_failed

Tags: functions, wp-login-form, core-modifications, wp-error

I am modifying my wp-login.php but from within functions.php (in order not to hack the core).

I need to disable one WP_error with code: authentication_failed.

if i hack the core and modify wp-login.php at the code:

```
foreach ( $wp_error->get_error_codes() as $code ) {
    $severity = $wp_error->get_error_data( $code );
    foreach ( $wp_error->get_error_messages( $code ) as $error_message ) {
            if ( 'message' == $severity )
                $messages .= '  ' . $error_message . "<br />\n";
            else
                $errors .= '    ' . $error_message . "<br />\n";
        }
}
```

to:

```
foreach ( $wp_error->get_error_codes() as $code ) {
        $severity = $wp_error->get_error_data( $code );
        if($code !=='authentication_failed'){ <======= ADDED
            foreach ( $wp_error->get_error_messages( $code ) as $error_message ) {
                  if ( 'message' == $severity )
                        $messages .= '  ' . $error_message . "<br />\n";
                  else
                        $errors .= '    ' . $error_message . "<br />\n";
            }
         }
}
```

It works. But I don't want to hack the core, is there a way to disable it from functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pluggable function wp_authenticate](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate) to override the core.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/

**Important caution:** Test this code on a sandbox before deploying live!

```
function wp_authenticate($username, $password) {
    $username = sanitize_user($username);
    $password = trim($password);

    $user = apply_filters( 'authenticate', null, $username, $password );

    if ( $user == null ) {
        $user = new WP_Error( 'authentication_failed', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.' ) );
    }

    $ignore_codes = array( 'authentication_failed' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) && !in_array( $user->get_error_code(), $ignore_codes ) ) {
        do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $username );
    }

    return $user;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_authenticate' );
```

Comment: it is breaking something on my end, i'll debug it and get back to you

Comment: @shadesco Yeah, I feared that. An option would be to look at the code in Limit Login Attempts https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/ (an old plugin, but still works fine) and see if maybe that gets you closer.